# Adding a shadow to a custom shape in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, view, shadow

I have a custom shaped view which has a top left radius of 0 and the other 3 radius are 16dp.

I am aware that you can override the outline provider however from what I see this doesn't allow you to set an outline where the radius on the corners is different.

Was wondering if there was any way of setting the outline provider for the specified shape or any other way to create a shadow on the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another view with the exact same size and corners but offset by a few dp on the x and y axes. Then offset the z so that it lays just underneath your original view. This should create the desired effect.